Can't get QField 3.3.8 to export the .qgs file, among other things
Very amateur question: when I attempt to export some of my current projects to a folder outside of the Android protected area, I often only get a partial export, omitting for example the .qgs file, along with much else.  The sequence of choices I am making is, from Home:
Open Local File
Imported Projects
From the 3 dots to the right of the folder to be exported:
export to folder, give access to use etc.
I do not recall this problem from earlier use, although I didn't export projects very often due to using a sync program to copy the stuff direct from the Android area.
I have not managed to isolate a reliable way to get the full export, although exporting to a different place with a different folder name seems to help.
